# How do I get the interior of the th tag on one line?

Tags: css

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pq9rj5b7/)

I would like to get From: textbox To: textbox all on one line.

```
<table class="table display" id="activeProjects">
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>Project Name</th>
            <th>Project Number</th>
            <th>Market</th>
            <th>Project Type</th>
            <th>Completion Date</th>
            <th>Square Footage</th>
            <th>Architect</th>
            <th>Manager</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th><p style="white-space: nowrap;">From: <input type="text" id="min" name="min" class="form-control numberFilter" /> To: <input class="form-control numberFilter" type="text" id="max" name="max" /></p></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr> 

    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="project in model.projects">
            <td></td>
            <td><a href></a></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Project Name</th>
            <th>Project Number</th>
            <th>Market</th>
            <th>Project Type</th>
            <th>Completion Date</th>
            <th>Square Footage</th>
            <th>Architect</th>
            <th>Manager</th>
        </tr>

    </tfoot>
</table>

.numberFilter {
width: 75px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your headings may need a tweak but try this:

```
.numberFilter {
    width: 15%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

You can edit the width value to suit, but that is just a guide. You won't be able to fix the width of the input in PX, unless you set the TH / TD widths.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the help of `display: table-row` & `display: table-cell`.

Wrap each of your 2 "cells" (text + input) in a placeholder element (for example, a `<span>`), set this wrapper element to `display: table-cell` and the `<p>` to `display: table-row`.

[Here's the fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pq9rj5b7/12/)

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers already.  You may run into cross browser issues with the table-row and table-cell css properties.  If you do, you can just give your input elements a "display: inline" and set the width of the column. Like so:

[js fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/pq9rj5b7/14/)

```
<input style="display: inline" />
```

notice the width set on the th element in the js fiddle code.